How to make ASP.NET Core 8 Web API for authenticated AND unauthenticated users
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that can be called using JWT authentication like so:
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<IRecord>> PostRecordA(Record rec)
{
    var id = await dbc.AddNew(rec);
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetRecord), new { id = id }, rec);
}

A new requirement is to allow non-authenticated users as well, and store the userid, so the database call would change to:
var id = await dbc.AddNew(uid, rec); // for authenticated users
// or
var id = await dbc.AddNew(0, rec);

Is there a way to make the [Authorize] attribute optional and get the JWT userid somehow?
Environment is ASP.NET Core 8, AWS cognito

I doesn't think there is a way to make it optional. I would remove the attribute and instead use User.Identity.IsAuthenticated to check whether the request were send from an authenticated user and then access the user id.

You can try to use custom model binding to check the identity status of the user in HttpContext, such as automatically binding a parameter such as userId to the ID of the authenticated user or the default value (such as 0) of the unauthenticated user, and check httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated to determine whether the authentication is passed. If it is passed, get the id and assign it to userId. If it is not passed, it is 0. Here is an example for your reference:
public class UserIdModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
       
        var httpContext = bindingContext.HttpContext;
        int userId = 0; 

        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
           // "Myapp_User_Id" is a custom claim type in my token
            var userIdClaim = httpContext.User.FindFirst("Myapp_User_Id");
            if (userIdClaim != null)
            {
                int.TryParse(userIdClaim.Value, out userId);
            }
        }

       
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(userId);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class UserIdModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(int) && context.Metadata.Name == "userId")
        {
            return new UserIdModelBinder();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

Storage method:
   [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostRecordA(User rec, [ModelBinder] int userId)
    {
          
      //  var id = await dbc.AddNew(userId, rec);
        return Ok(userId);  
   
    }

When the authentication fails, the id is recorded as 0:

When the authentication is passed, the id is recorded as the user id:


But it should be noted that the identifiers for extracting user IDs may be different for different jwt authentications,You may need to adjust the extracting ID claim type identifier.
